# tape.gradient for model.trainable_variables returning None value

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Here is my Function:

```
def grad(self,model,ytrain, x_train):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:         
            loss_value = self.calculate_loss(ytrain, self.pred)
            #Value of loss_value is tf.Tensor(182.1716, shape=(), dtype=float32)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value,model.trainable_variables)
        return loss_value,grads
```

Upon printing grads value its giving me this answer:
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
(As I have a Convolutional Neural Network)

Here is my Network Architecture

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 608, 608, 8)       224

---

leaky_re_lu_234 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 608, 608, 8)       0

---

pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 304, 304, 8)       0

---

conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 304, 304, 16)      1168

---

leaky_re_lu_235 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 304, 304, 16)      0

---

pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 152, 152, 16)      0

---

conv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 152, 152, 64)      9280

---

leaky_re_lu_236 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 152, 152, 64)      0

---

conv4 (Conv2D)               (None, 152, 152, 64)      36928

---

leaky_re_lu_237 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 152, 152, 64)      0

---

conv5 (Conv2D)               (None, 152, 152, 128)     73856

---

leaky_re_lu_238 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 152, 152, 128)     0

---

pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 76, 76, 128)       0

---

conv6 (Conv2D)               (None, 76, 76, 256)       295168

---

leaky_re_lu_239 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 76, 76, 256)       0

---

conv7 (Conv2D)               (None, 76, 76, 128)       295040

---

leaky_re_lu_240 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 76, 76, 128)       0

---

conv8 (Conv2D)               (None, 76, 76, 256)       295168

---

leaky_re_lu_241 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 76, 76, 256)       0

---

pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 38, 38, 256)       0

---

conv9 (Conv2D)               (None, 38, 38, 512)       1180160

---

leaky_re_lu_242 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 38, 38, 512)       0

---

conv10 (Conv2D)              (None, 38, 38, 256)       1179904

---

leaky_re_lu_243 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 38, 38, 256)       0

---

conv11 (Conv2D)              (None, 38, 38, 128)       295040

---

leaky_re_lu_244 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 38, 38, 128)       0

---

conv12 (Conv2D)              (None, 38, 38, 64)        73792

---

leaky_re_lu_245 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 38, 38, 64)        0

---

conv13 (Conv2D)              (None, 38, 38, 32)        18464

---

leaky_re_lu_246 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 38, 38, 32)        0

---

pool5 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 19, 19, 32)        0

---

## conv14 (Conv2D)              (None, 19, 19, 5)         1445

Total params: 3,755,637
Trainable params: 3,755,637
Non-trainable params: 0

I have also referred to https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/eager.ipynb#scrollTo=C5dGz0p_nf4W link.
I have checked the data type and format of the variable. Its the same, But still getting None value in tape.gradient statement.

This is the Error:

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv1_23/kernel:0', 'conv1_23/bias:0', 'conv2_23/kernel:0', 'conv2_23/bias:0', 'conv3_23/kernel:0', 'conv3_23/bias:0', 'conv4_23/kernel:0', 'conv4_23/bias:0', 'conv5_23/kernel:0', 'conv5_23/bias:0', 'conv6_23/kernel:0', 'conv6_23/bias:0', 'conv7_23/kernel:0', 'conv7_23/bias:0', 'conv8_23/kernel:0', 'conv8_23/bias:0', 'conv9_23/kernel:0', 'conv9_23/bias:0', 'conv10_23/kernel:0', 'conv10_23/bias:0', 'conv11_23/kernel:0', 'conv11_23/bias:0', 'conv12_23/kernel:0', 'conv12_23/bias:0', 'conv13_23/kernel:0', 'conv13_23/bias:0', 'conv14_23/kernel:0', 'conv14_23/bias:0'].

when executing the statement:
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also having the same issue

Comment: @Siladittya did you find the answer? Could you please share?